# Using StringFormat in a Binding to display Hex value with spaces

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, string-formatting

I haven't been able to figure out how to use StringFormat to display hex as:

```
08 A4 23 F5
```

Specifically I want the spaces after every 2 characters. When I do this:

```
Text="{Binding MyIntValue, StringFormat={}{0:x}}"
```

It looks like this:

```
08A423F5
```

My backup plan is using a converter on the binding but I would like to know if is possible to do it with just StringFormat.

Comment: @baueric - `MyIntValue` is of type string or what?

Comment: @RohitVats it's an int.

Comment: @ValeraScherbakov That prints out the value as an integer with spaces in between the digits.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#XFormatString) says about the `The hexadecimal ("X") format specifier` and after having a play with [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx), I don't think this is possible in quite way you're after.

I think you'll either have to use a `Converter` like you suggested (probably making use of a `BitConverter`). Or just exposing a string property formatted in the way you desire.

Comment: I'm thinking you are correct. After trying many things I have to say it is probably beyond the scope of what StringFormat can provide. However, I can't say it is solved. I must leave it open in the event someone does come along with an answer.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, I've starred the question as I was also hoping someone appears and says "Here's the magic string you need!", without any fancy extensions =D